# Export and download query results to Excel file in PHP from oracle

Tags: php, oracle, phpexcel, export-to-excel

```
// Export results
require_once('PHPExcel.php');
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT TITLE, PID, TYPE, SUM(DAYCOUNT) AS tot, ROUND(SUM(DAYCOUNT)/( SELECT SUM(DAYCOUNT) FROM REPORT_LIST_VIEW), 4) AS per FROM REPORT_LIST_VIEW WHERE DAYCOUNT > '0' GROUP BY TITLE, PID, TYPE ORDER BY tot DESC";
if ($result = db_query($query)) {
    // Create a new PHPExcel object
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('List of Cities');
    // Loop through the result set
    $rowNumber = 1;
    while ($row = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($row,NULL,'A'.$rowNumber++);
    }
    // Save as an Excel BIFF (xls) file
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save('CityList.xls');
}
```

I tried this code in a PHP page to download query results from Oracle as an Excel file, but when I browse to the page, it is all blank and white like it is hung.

Any clues?

Comment: In same folder where your php file exists find there will be an excel will present

Comment: No its not there. Can i  download CityList.xls to my local?.

Comment: Assuming that both PHPExcel.php and de SELECT are correct...
Do remote user have the right to write on that folder? Did you check your errors log?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code that will download the excel file in local system Check folder permission as well

**To download the excel file you need to set headers.So simply provide filename which will be the name of downloaded excel file.**

```
// Export results
require_once('PHPExcel.php');
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT TITLE, PID, TYPE, SUM(DAYCOUNT) AS tot, ROUND(SUM(DAYCOUNT)/( SELECT SUM(DAYCOUNT) FROM REPORT_LIST_VIEW), 4) AS per FROM REPORT_LIST_VIEW WHERE DAYCOUNT > '0' GROUP BY TITLE, PID, TYPE ORDER BY tot DESC";
if ($result = db_query($query)) {
    // Create a new PHPExcel object
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('List of Cities');
    // Loop through the result set
    $rowNumber = 1;
    while ($row = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($row,NULL,'A'.$rowNumber++);
    }



// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="CityList.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header ('Expires: Fri, 11 Sep 2015 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date
header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried the updated code. But no were i found `CityList.xls` file. Either in my local or in web root folder.

Comment: Using the headers and php://output sends the file to a web browser... did you get the file save dialogue in your browser when accessing the page?