# PHPExcel+MySQL Export per row

Tags: php, excel

Is it possible to export specific row in MySQL to excel?
All I found in the internet is whole table exported.
How about per line?

Comment: Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32516841/export-and-download-query-results-to-excel-file-in-php-from-oracle/32517079#32517079 . You can then put the exact where clause for the query. Or you can loop through the rows retrieved, pick up the exact row and put it to Excel

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use mysqldump like below.

exec('mysqldump --user=... --password=... --host=... DB_NAME --where= > /path/to/output/file.sql');